# Cannot find module express Babel-node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Ok, so I have a file structure like this:

[image]

My package.json file looks like this:

[image]

My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

[image]

But, when I try running

`babel-node server.js`

I get this error:

[image]

My server.js file looks like this:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";

app.use(cors());

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port 9000`);
});
```

thanks for any help!

EDIT: Yes express is installed, and I had it installed before I asked the question

Comment: I suggest you add the error as plain text inside your **question** and not like an image

Comment: Did you actually install express, or did you just edit your package.json?

Comment: I installed it wow

Comment: Does that mean it works now?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, navigate to the directory which contains that `package.json` and run `npm install`.

If you've already done that, do it again and ensure there were no errors while installing.